# Варианты название файла с расширением .js и его альтернативные варианты

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Какие имена можно создавать какие нет.Искал мануал - Не нашел. 
Мои варианты-хотелки:

- example_JS.js
- example_01.js

Если такие имена нельзя создавать опишите проблемы  которые они тянут за собой.

Очень "хочетца" пулю с самонаведением и многоразовостью чтоб после пробивание первого оборотня летела за следующим. 
Это я про java ;)

Пожалуйста, помогите советом/знаниями!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как таковых правил и рекомендаций по именованию файлов не встречал. Но есть некоторые рекомендации, которых я стараюсь придерживаться во время именования файлов в JavaScript:

- Более привычно использовать имена файлов в нижнем регистре (лично для
  меня и всех проектов, в которых я веду работу).
- Не использовать пробелы в именах файлов, лучше использовать тире или
  точку. Использовать тире, когда слова связаны по смыслу, к примеру
  имя продукта в два слова через тире.Точку, когда идет разделение
  логики, к примеру имя модуля и версия - разделим точкой.
- Использовать номера версии в именах файлов, если таковые имеются.
- Использовать в именах файлов пространство имен, имя модуля, тип файла
  (на примере именования в jQuery). Например:
  product-name.plugin-version.filetype.js или jquery.plugin-0.1.js

Comment: Спасибо)  где-то недавно читал это )

можете уточнить,  а вот так чем хуже Plugin_01.js этого "plugin-0.1.js"?

Comment: Лично мне не имеет значение как названо, но...
Это всё зависит от восприятия человека. Людям легче воспринимать - , чем _ . 
Когда читаешь название фала, то легче пробежаться по прямой глазами, чем вверх и вниз ими размахивать во время просмотра.

Comment: Тоже думаю что все от восприятия зависит. Например

Comment: Кстати, нижнее подчёркивание ещё расшифровывается как "пробел".

Comment: Тоже думаю что все от восприятия зависит. Например точку я воспринимаю как вложенность отсюда и названия допустим вот такое jquery.plugin-0.1.js Но если имена придумываются  как много несвязных между собой флагов, асациативно-интуитивных и понятных лишь при привязке в конкретной задаче (если нет структурно построенной архитектуры от которой можно плясать) ?
Мне вот тире нравится в меньшей степени т.к. при чтении_проше_пробежаться_по_отдельным_словам нежели  разбираться-в-сплошном-тексте.  Правила UI/UX - разделенные на куски портянки выглядит менее страшно :)

Comment: Если точнее, подчеркивание воспринимается как пробел. Нижнее подчеркивание насколько я представляю являться спецсимволом. На проектах сталкивался с аналогией, что не заполненное поле можно  сравнить  с пробелом, но проверять все равно в кейсах приходилось оба варианта и пробел и пустое поле.

Comment: Получил ответ при переписке в комментариях. Как на этой площадке ставится  лайк коментарию ???

Comment: Возле комментария, слева, есть стрелка вверх. Это и есть лайк комментарию.

Comment: У меня возможно не отображается, вот как у меня - https://prnt.sc/oay53l

Comment: Не знаю с чем это связано, но у меня есть. Изображение по ссылке: https://wmpics.pics/di-1B7H.png

Comment: А где вопрос такой задать можно и какую метку ставить в нем,

Comment: Не совсем понял о чём ты. Можешь подробнее описать вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос задал в новом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы можно называть как угодно. Но нельзя применять запрещенные символы - * | / \ : ' " < > ? @ # $ % ^ & ( ). Подправьте, если где-то не прав.

Comment: есть ссылка, чтобы про запреты почитать ?

Comment: Ну, вообще, это в интернете есть и легко найти. А так - http://compbasic.ru/filenames-restrictions-in-window/ 
Еще -  https://www.remoteshaman.com/windows/common/spisok-zapreshhyonnyx-imyon-dlya-fajlov-i-katalogov-v-windows

Comment: Вы правы нельзя применять символы, которые запрещённые в названии файлов. Их и ввести не получается. 
 Очень хочется понять в чем преимущество конкретных имен над другими чем обусловлено не использование нижнего подчеркивание взамен точке например.

Comment: Сомнительный список запрещённых символов. Ни подо что не подходит...